# Is there a way for a PostgresQL procedure to somehow print out its table context for test purpose?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am a new man for PostgresQL; working in DBEaver. I have created a procedure that modifies, among others, a temp table. I would like to print out the table for testing purposes: to see what is in the table now.

In T-SQL I could just execute “select * from MyTestTable”; and this was output to SQL Studio Grid tab. This did not break the procedure.

Now on Postgres I am using DBeaver and get errors when I try to use the same approach.

A question to experienced PostgresQL: how you cope with that? Is there any way to “peek my nose” into middle of a proc and see – what data are at given moment in table. If no - how to debug large and complicated procedures without ability to look at produced data Grid?

Comment: Write it out to non-temporary table outside the function? Something like `select * into permanent_table from temporary_table`. See [Select Into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) or [Create Table As](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html).

Comment: Thank you; but outside the function I also do not have any non-temporary tables.

Comment: On further thought you should use `CREATE TABLE AS ...` because `SELECT INTO ...` will conflict with `plpgsql select into`per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW`CREATE TABLE AS ... `will create one on the fly. In your function you could have `DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS <some_table_name>;` then `CREATE TABLE  <some_table_name> AS select * from temporary_table`. Then outside the function you could ` select * from <some_table_name>` to see what in the temporary table at the time the `CREATE TABLE <some_table_name> AS ...` was done.